# Android gridview equivalent for earlier sdk

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a detail view to display mostly textviews. I think that a gridview would be ideal, it doesn't seem to work well with my project which I use ActionBarSherlock for downward compatibility.  I've tried using both relative layout and table layout, but I'm not sure how to accomplish what I want.

Here is what I have so far, but I need to have the first column width no greater than the element in it, ie: image, multiline textview, etc..:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lemon" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5sp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/placard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/material"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:textColor="#0000ff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/div_text"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:paddingTop="5sp"
            android:text="@string/division"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/division"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:paddingTop="5sp"
            android:textColor="#0000ff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hazards"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:paddingTop="5sp"
            android:textColor="#0000ff"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Haven't used ActionBarSherlock , why is that causing you problem in using GridView? Also, using a Table Layout can make your view "looks" like a GridView but never something similar to the actual one (you may notice major performance issue if you have hundreds of items).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I actually meant GridLayout which in new in API 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to `GridLayout`, which was introduced in API 14 (Android 4.0).  However, the latest version of the support library includes a library project that you can use to incorporate `GridLayout` into your application and have it compatible back to API 7 (Android 2.1).

Because you are trying to make the rows asymmetric from one to the other, I believe `GridLayout` may still be your best (only) option.

Here is a link to the [support library page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have tried the support.V7.widget.GridLayout library.  Unfortunately, there were some issues with that and the views do not display properly compared to the API 14 Gridlayout widget.  The latest support package is suppose to have fixes, but I haven't figured out how to incorporate it into my project.